# How can I disable the recovery mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to disable the recover mode on Windows 7, so that no matter what error occurs it will always try and boot normally?

Comment: Are you referring to the screen that pops up when say, you powercycle the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click My Computer, select properties.
2. Click "Advanced system settings"
3. Under Startup and Recovery click the "Settings..." button.
   There is an option for "Time to display recovery options when needed"

You can try unchecking this (if already checked) or you can try checking it and setting the time to zero.